# xcode problem with importing libraries

Tags: xcode, json, cocos2d-iphone, libraries, sharekit

I have a project containing cocos2d framework, sharekit, asi & json.
I've noticed that for example Reachability.m/h and some other files exists in more than one framework.
How do I solve this problem?

Here's the error from transcript

```
ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Reachability.reachabilityRef in /Users/fredrik/Workspace/********/build/********.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/********.build/Objects-normal/i386/Reachability-89CD930C57F9E55C.o and /Users/fredrik/Workspace/********/build/********.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/********.build/Objects-normal/i386/Reachability-6FEC7F1ECD12144E.o
```

I'm using Xcode 3.2.4 with iOS 4.2 and OS X 10.6.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete all but one copy. Move that single copy out of the containing library folder (for your sanity's sake).

Comment: I get 50 errors instead of one if I move the file. Do I have to change the refs in all the other files in that framework?

Comment: You may need to update your "Header Search Path" in the target's build settings, depending on what is being moved around.

Comment: Ok, I've managed to include asi but JSON is still struggling. cocos2d already have a JSON lib but it's not the lib I want. It doesn't have the exakt same functions as http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/ I can't delete TouchJSON files from cocos2d and I can't include the other framework either.